# JMeter / java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"

Tags: java, jenkins, jmeter

In the JMeter [Report Dashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UN3sm.png) I want have 'Start Time' and 'End Time' in the simple data format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss', but I see error in jmeter.log and the time format remains the same.

```
2017/03/20 04:47:22 ERROR - jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration: Error parsing property jmeter.reportgenerator.start_date with value: dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss using format: dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
at org.apache.jmeter.report.config.ReportGeneratorConfiguration.loadFromProperties(ReportGeneratorConfiguration.java:663)
at org.apache.jmeter.report.dashboard.ReportGenerator.<init>(ReportGenerator.java:159)
at org.apache.jmeter.JMeter.start(JMeter.java:480)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.apache.jmeter.NewDriver.main(NewDriver.java:259)
```

I tried the various methods described in [Date and Time Patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html), but the result is always the same. The same problem in the local Windows PC.

Answer (score 0):

The `jmeter.reportgenerator.start_date` parameter should be a date not a date format.

The format is set via the `jmeter.reportgenerator.date_format` parameter.

You end up sending the format string to the `parse` method DateFormat and not the date string.

```
final DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");

/*
 * Exception in thread "main" java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss"
 * at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:366)
 * at com.stackoverflow.q42914755.Answer.main(Answer.java:18)
 */
Date date = dateFormat.parse("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Comment: The point is that I pass this parameter in the JMeter in the user.properties file. And it describes the date format:                                                          # Date range start date using date_format property
jmeter.reportgenerator.start_date=dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss

Comment: I tried to pass a parameter in such variants: dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss, "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss", 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss ', but the result is always the same.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, your answer pushed me in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

Jeff, thanks for the help!
The problem was in the parameter "jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format"
It was jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format = ms
But it should be set to the value jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format = dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss